# Did the US government ever burn corn?

Tags: united-states, economy, agriculture

I remember hearing and/or reading that the US government burned corn (or destroyed it) at some point. This was not because there was anything wrong with the corn, but rather because by buying it they could sustain higher prices for the corn (pleasing corn farmers); as presumably their reserves were already full, it was disposed of.

I can't find anything that substantiates this recollection. The closest I can find is stories about the [US government paying farmers to *not* grow crops](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/making-sense/why-does-the-govt-pay-farmers/). Has anybody else heard the same story of the government actually destroying corn? Can anybody point me to a source?

Comment: Sounds familiar, but I didn't find anything on a search, other than one random comment claiming the same on a WSJ article.

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=3hGJBAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=roosevelt+%22burn+crops%22+depression&ots=0ivbO5WfkO&sig=UtmN7hekeWH6OIDe5T9SE-aEOpg#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20crops%22&f=false) claims that some burnt their crops in the Depression, but it does not claim government intervention to do so.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wickard_v._Filburn

Comment: I remember learning that this was one of the New Deal measures FDR took to stabilise food prices during the Great Depression. The textbook said something like, "It didn't seem right to many for the government to burn food while millions of Americans were starving."

Comment: In Brazil in the 30s they used dried coffee to power locomotives... which was more useful than just throwing the excess production at sea. http://makezine.com/2007/01/17/using-coffee-as-fuel-in-b/

Comment: @Semaphore Yes, that sounds right. If you come across a source for that, please do let me know.

Comment: There's some reference to destroying oranges here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agricultural_Adjustment_Act And it mentions the burning of corn for fuel instead of coal, but this was done on a household level, seemingly not by government directive.

Comment: Just to be a pain in the butt, I should point out that lots of people [burn corn](http://www.backwoodshome.com/i-heat-my-house-by-burning-corn/).  It's a decent competitor to wood pellets in wood stoves.  :)

Comment: Unlike other crops, such as oranges, corn stores well and there are many uses for surplus. You can dry it and grind it into meal. It's people food and animal food. You can turn it into whiskey for easier transport, very common in places far from market. You can burn the cobs and husks for heat and power. You can turn it into ethanol to power machines. And unlike fruit trees which take years to mature, corn is planted annually and can respond faster to market changes. So I have my doubts there would be a need to systematically burn corn to prop up prices.

Answer (score 1):

Henry Ford first ran his "automobile" on ethanol so I think any government policy to burn corn is highly suspect at best. Using corn instead of wood for fueling a stove for cooking was quite common too "in days of yore." Again I wouldn't call this a "policy" however.

Comment: Again, I think ethanol is distracting from my question. I had a recollection of the government purchasing and destroying corn as a way to support higher corn prices. Perhaps this was apocryphal, but at least one other user has heard of a similar story. In any case, I would interpret your answer as "no," i.e. the government never burned corn. Of course, it's rather difficult to prove the negative!

Comment: I suspect they burned just the cobs and husks.